# Hacer varios Update a la vez

Tags: php, mysql, update

Tengo una tabla mysql así:

```
codigo   estado
   1      'v'
   2      's'
   3      'a'
   4      't'
   5      'v'
```

Y quiero evitar hacer tantas llamadas con el for:

```
$codigos=json_decode($_REQUEST['codigos'], true); // $_REQUEST['codigos']='[1,2,4]';
for($i=0;$i<count($codigos);$i++){
  $mysqli->query("update tabla set estado='x' where cod=$codigos[$i]") or die($mysqli->error);
}
```

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Échale un ojo a `IN` de mysql. Puedes hacer `where cod IN (*ARRAY DE CODIGOS AQUI*)`.

Comment: Tu código es susceptible a [Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/16597)

Comment: Esto me sale al intentar con IN : Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucioné de esta forma, aunque no sé si sea la mejor:

```
$codigos=substr($_REQUEST['codigos'], 1, -1); //$_REQUEST['codigos']='[1,2,4]';
$mysqli->query("update tabla set estado='x' where codigo in ($codigos)") or die($mysqli->error);
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor, lee [answer] y edita tu respuesta para añadir más detalles (p.e. una breve descripción de lo que hace el código y/o cómo soluciona el problema). De ese modo podrá ser de más ayuda para otros usuarios.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta con esto

```
$codigos=json_decode($_REQUEST['codigos'], true); // $_REQUEST['codigos']='[1,2,4]';
$mysqli->query("update tabla set estado='x' where cod IN $codigos") or die($mysqli->error);
```

Comment: No me funcionó,

Comment: Listo, no habia quitado la [i], prueba nuevamente @ArturoRodas

Comment: Tampoco funciona, sale: Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

Comment: Ya vi el problema. 
SQL por naturaleza dentro de las clausulas de IN recoge los valores dentro de parentesis () mientras que tu los envias como array [], corrigiendo eso, deberia funcionarte el IN. @ArturoRodas

Comment: Aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor, lee [answer] y edita tu respuesta para añadir más detalles (p.e. una breve descripción de lo que hace el código y/o cómo soluciona el problema). De ese modo podrá ser de más ayuda para otros usuarios.